# illegal instruction occur while using pointer and reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, illegal-instruction

when reading [the source codes of realtime_tools::RealtimeBuffer](http://docs.ros.org/en/hydro/api/realtime_tools/html/realtime__buffer_8h_source.html#l00119), I got lots of questions about the pointer and reference. The related codes are shown below:

```
void writeFromNonRT(const T& data)
{
    // get lock
    lock();

    // copy data into non-realtime buffer
    *non_realtime_data_ = data;
    new_data_available_ = true;

    // release lock
    mutex_.unlock();
}
```

To figure out, I tried to code the similar code like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void pt_ref(int& data) 
{
    int *ptr;        
    ptr = &data;    // ptr points to "data"
    cout << "data's addres： "<< ptr <<"\n"; // print address
}

int main() 
{
    int x = 3;
    pt_ref(x);
    cout << "x's address： " << &x;
}
\\ output:
\\ data's addres： 0x7ffe05c17c4c
\\ x's address： 0x7ffe05c17c4c
```

This code runs well, but it's still different to the source code.

```
// these 2 lines are different.
*non_realtime_data_ = data;
ptr = &data;
```

So I tried to change `ptr = &data;` to `*ptr = data;`, and ran again the code, the error("illegal instruction") occurred.

Hope someone can answer me, thanks a lot.

PS: I ran the code on the replit online compiler.

Comment: Did you initialize `ptr` to point to a valid memory address you can write to? It sounds like you did not. You might consider adding the code you're having trouble with to the question.

Comment: When you changed that line you dereferenced an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: RetiredNinja, Taekahn, thanks for answering my question. I tried to understand what you explained. My understanding is that:

```ptr = &data;``` make ptr point to data
```*ptr = data;``` make ptr change the value in its "address" to data, but I didn't initialize the "address", so I got the error.

Is it right?

Comment: Correct. Though I would direct you to Anna’s well written answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to change ptr = &data; to *ptr = data;, and ran again the code, the error("illegal instruction") occurred.

The **problem** is that the the pointer `ptr` was **uninitialized**(and does not point to any `int` object) and so dereferencing that pointer(which you did when you wrote `*ptr` on the left hand side) leads to **undefined behavior**.

```
    int *ptr;   //pointer ptr does not point to any int object as of now    
   *ptr = data;
//-^^^^--------->undefined behavior since ptr doesn't point to any int object
```

---

To solve this make sure that before dereferencing `ptr`, the pointer `ptr` points to some `int` object.

```
void pt_ref(int& data) 
{
    int var = 10; //int object
//-------------vvvv-------->now ptr points to "var"
    int *ptr = &var; 
//--vvvv------------------->this is fine now       
    *ptr = data;             
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so after ```*ptr = data```, the value of ```var``` will be changed to the data, right?

Comment: @RyanChen.YLC Yes, exactly.